# .Net maui package problems

Tags: .net, maui

[image: what is the solution?]

I only added Communitytoolkit.maui package. But I didn't understand the problem.

```
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

<TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>

<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
```

Comment: Show all rows from your proj file, that start with "<SupportedOSPlatformVersion". Not as image, as text lines.

Comment: Is this IOS only app? Are there other lines?

Comment: This here: <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion> change 11 to 21

Comment: It dosen't work.

Comment: I am having really hard time believing you that "only  added Communitytoolkit.maui". This project line leads to the last error of your list of errors. There you need to add API version, not Android version. API version 11 in that line, means Android 3. Minimum for MAUI is android 5 (API version 21). Adding community toolkit will not write such non-sense in your project file. Make the changes I told you to do, and try to build again, and see if the last error disappears.

Comment: @H.A.H. Chill no need to get so serious, The OP Seems new and needs to learn a thing or two in both StackOverflow and MAUI. CeydaPak Are you sure the only change you have made is adding that package?

Comment: @FreakyAli I am always chill and serious. And the answer to your question is obvious.

Comment: @H.A.H I changed 11 to 21 already. But I'm still getting errors.

Comment: Downgrade all nuget packages. (It builds correctly on my side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using .NET 9 packages with your .NET 8 Projects,

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="9.0.0-preview.1.9973" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="9.0.0-preview.1.9973" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="9.0.0-preview.1.24080.9" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Graphics" Version="9.0.0-preview.1.9973" />
```

Disable include pre-release in your NuGet package manager and then downgrade to version 8's that are not pre-release for all above packages

For instance, I currently have these 2 packages in my .NET 8 project at the following version

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.7" />
```